# Trouble setting up an online GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm a complete Git novice and I'm trying to install and set up a repo (Text Analyzer) so I can work on a project with someone else. I have the repo set up on my desktop so that if I open Git GUI or GitHub I have full functionality. My problem is that I can't get the repo to connect to github.com in any way. The website claims I have no repos at all.

I'm not sure what to ask here because I'm not entirely clear on how GitHub works. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a repository on GitHub and add it as a remote to your existing local repo.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:your-username/name-of-your-repo.git
```

Then you just need to push your local changes to remote (assuming that you commited locally).

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this a few times but got the error

"Fatal: Not a git repository: .git"

I can't explain this because the repo definitely exists online and is fully set up. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: so you first need to initialize the local repository with `git init` and then add and commit some files with `git add` and `git commit`. If you go to your repo on github you should see these instructions there.